# Set L2CAP streaming mode in BlueZ

Tags: bluetooth, streaming, bluez, l2cap

I need to create a simple L2CAP connection on BlueZ with the streaming mode enabled. Does anyone know how I can switch modes? At the moment, the connection has re-transmission enabled, and I need to cancel all re-transmissions.